# Insert date in Oracle table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I managed to connect to the Oracle database for express edition. I created a table :

```
CREATE TABLE out_patient 
( 
     patient_id    NUMBER(8) PRIMARY KEY, 
     first_name    VARCHAR2(20), 
     last_name     VARCHAR2(20), 
     gender        VARCHAR2(10), 
     mobile_number NUMBER(12), 
     address       VARCHAR2(20), 
     date_of_birth DATE, 
     date_of_entry DATE 
);
```

Now I have a form to fill up all these details but, I'm getting an **sqlexception:**

> ORA-01861:literals does not match format string

Can you tell what's causing it. Am I entering data in wrong format? I guess it might be due to 2 dates Date_Of_Birth and Date_Of_Entry. 
In my JDBC code I'm doing this:

```
String t1=text_dob.getText(); 
String t2=text_doe.getText();
```

and then,

```
st.setStrin(7,t1); 
st.setString(8,t2);
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setDate()` instead of `setString` on `PreparedStatement`:

```
st.setDate(7, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
st.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
st.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

You problem happens because your DDL column is set to `Date` so Oracle expects `Date` value but you are sending `VARCHAR` value.

Timestamp: see [types mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)

> java.sql.Date for SQL DATE information. The hour, minute, second, and
>   millisecond fields of the java.util.Date base class should be set to
>   zero. If the number of milliseconds supplied to the java.sql.Date
>   constructor is negative, the driver will compute the date as the
>   number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970. Otherwise, the date is
>   computed as the specified number of milliseconds after January 1,
>   1970.
>
> java.sql.Time for SQL TIME information. The year, month, and day
>   fields of the java.util.Date base class are set to 1970, January, and
>   1. This is the "zero" date in the Java epoch.
>
> java.sql.Timestamp for SQL TIMESTAMP information. This class extends
>   java.util.Date by adding a nanoseconds field.

Comment: Hey! i searched over some of other posts here and found out '02-JAN-2013' works well and i entered date in this format ,it worked fine.i'll try the setDate() as well.

Comment: can you please tell me how to insert time as well.columns type is Time.by default which format ?or any setTime().

Comment: You need to pass java.sql.TimeStamp in Java

Comment: It is there, I updated my answer. You have to use setTimestamp(int, Timestamp) method

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your date entered in the GUI field is in the "dd/MM/yyyy" format. Adjust the pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` accordingly if it is different..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFomat("dd/MM/yyyy");
st.setDate(7,new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(text_dob.getText()).getTime()));
st.setDate(8,new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(text_doe.getText()).getTime()));
```

In case your GUI field contains date and time like "31/01/2014 23:59:59", the corresponding pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` is "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss". You can read the `SimpleDateFormat` docs for full pattern format.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Modified answer so to call getTime() on java.util.Date and construct a new java.sql.Date.

Comment: yeah!! i was getting an erro.but why getTime() ??is it necessary?

Comment: @user3367768 calling getTime() on java.util.Date to get the milliseconds since epoch. Then use this to construct the java.sql.Date

Comment: can you tell me the same conversions for TIMESTAMP ,please.

Comment: hey tell me how to convert time into TIMESTAMP for storing in database.thanks

Comment: @user3367768 java.sql.Date itself IS a timestamp. It contains date and time information. Your Oracle Date type also contains date and time information.

Comment: Btw did you try your timestamp proposal? I am sure that setDate() will not pass time part of date.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Your question is valid and I have not tried it. But I think I have used I successfully in the past. The Oracle<->JDBC mapping says it is OK to use. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/basic3.htm

Comment: I know from my past projects that it does not work and you must use Timestamp.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I guess it very much depends on the database and the driver used. I use Oracle and the Oracle Thin JDBC driver.

Comment: Pity I do not have oracle db, I would try that.

Comment: "The JDBC DATE type represents a date consisting of day, month, and year." - e.g. if you call setDate(TimeStamp), the time is discarded.